# how to change MaxDiskUsage for dump file on windows ce

Tags: windows-ce, crash-dumps, windows-error-reporting

I enabled [error reporting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms939656.aspx) feature on Windows CE platform to gather dump file for crashed application. I set default dump type to [system dumps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms939598.aspx). But we can only get context dumps.

Msdn states:

> Typically, the Error Reporting system generates a system dump. However, if the size of the dump file generated would be larger than the space allocated to it, the system generates a  much smaller context dump.

It seems error reporting only allows us to set MaxDiskUsage to 512kb at maximum. Is there any way to set MaxDiskUsage to a larger value?

Answer (score 0):

Using the following registry settings you can adjust the Maximum dump usage.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\ErrorReporting\DumpSettings]
"ReservedDumpMemory"=dword:80000
"DumpDirectory"="\\Hard Disk\\DumpFile"
"ExtraFilesDirectory"="\\Hard Disk\\ExtraDumpFiles"
"DumpEnabled"=dword:1
"DumpType"=dword:3
"MaxDiskUsage"=dword:10000000
"MaxDumpSize"=dword:8000000
"MaxLogFileSize"=dword:8000000
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried, but it didn't work. I changed MaxDumpSize to a larger value, it was always reverted to 512k. Any clues?